# @font-face not rendering in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, css, font-face

In the **Chrome** browser on **Android** phones, `@font-face` is not rendering the 3 words under the logo properly at http://dev.belugalab.com/btm. However, the same font seems to be working in the footer. I'm not sure if this is related to *font-face*, but that is my best guess. This is a screenshot of what's happening on the **Android Chrome**: http://imm.io/MgE0

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'intro_regular';
    src: url('fonts/intro-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/fonts/intro-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/intro-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/intro-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/intro-webfont.svg#intro_regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}

h2 {
    font-family:'intro_regular';
    font-size:31px;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    margin:3px 0 4px 39px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:0 4px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It renders correctly on Chrome for iOS.  I don't have an Android device to see it, but try making your H2 line-height and height the same or more than the font-size.  They are currently 1 pixel shorter than your font-size.

Comment: By the way "Chrome for iOS" isn't Chrome. It's a wrapped UIWebView, a crippled Safari. Apple's fault, not Google's.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Android phone, but from looking at the screen shot it looks like the h2 doesn't even have the same font. When opening the page in Chrome (Mac) and unchecking the "font-family" (in Developer Tools) it looks a lot closer to the screenshot. When I remove the `line-height` tag and increase the size of the text a bit it looks just like the Android screenshot.

I would try removing the `height` and `line-height` and adjust the `padding` to get closer to what you want. That will at the very least prevent the text from getting cut off.

I suspect something wrong with the `'intro_regular'` font. Perhaps the Android Chrome is using a different font format than the desktop? SVG perhaps?

My first suspicion was another CSS rule overriding another on Android but not the desktop. But I couldn't find any other rules that would do that.

Have you tried clearing the cache on the Android Chrome?